# Single InstallJammer Project for Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, installation

How can I create a Single InstallJammer setup for both Windows and Linux? I have a sampleProject with the default components.I need to add a component that checks the OS version and proceed according to the result.

Please avoid giving the installJammer and TCL scripts tutorials as I have already read both of them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the **General Information > Platform Information** section, expand the platforms you want (e.g., Linux x86 and Windows) and make sure to set the **Active** property to **Yes** on each one. Have a look on other properties as well to be aware of the values and maybe customize something to fit your needs.
2. On the **Install User Interface > Install Panes and Actions** is where you can do the "conditional" behaviour. Once you create an *Action Group* you can set it's **Condition** property by clicking on the three dots in the end of the input line. A *Conditions for...* window will be shown, and there you can add a new **Platform Condition**. Set the advanced property **Platform** of this contition to the specific platform you want that action to be executed.

[image: Install Jammer action group condition]

As an example, you may want to create different actions to copy different *file groups*, a group of Windows specific files, and another group for Linux specific files (and you can also define a shared files group).

3. Go to the **Run Build > Build Installers** section and enable those platforms you want it to generate build installers.